# Xamarin Forms Get All Values from Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get all the values and store them in an array.[image]

I do not want to store them in a list. I want to store them in an array like.

string[] Names = {"Mark", "Andrea"};

My firebase helper class is

```
public async Task<List<Person>> GetAllPersons()
        {

            return (await firebase
              .Child("Persons")
              .OnceAsync<Person>()).Select(item => new Person
              {
                  Name = item.Object.Name,
                  PersonId = item.Object.PersonId,
                  Age = item.Object.Age
              }).ToList();
        }

public async Task<Person> GetOne()
        {
            var allPersons = await GetAllPersons();
            await firebase
              .Child("Persons")
              .OnceAsync<Person>();
            return allPersons.First();
        }
```

In my MainPage I have

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {

            base.OnAppearing();
            var allPersons = await firebaseHelper.GetAllPersons();
            lstPersons.ItemsSource = allPersons;

            var person = await firebaseHelper.GetOne();

            string[] Names;

            //Names = person.Age;

            Console.WriteLine(person.Name);

            test.Text = person.Name;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public async Task<string[]> GetAllPersonsNames()
        {

            return (await firebase
              .Child("Persons")
              .OnceAsync<Person>()).Select(item =>
              item.Object.Name).ToArray();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another `List<string>`, then traverse the `List<Person> allPersons`. In the end, you can convert it back to an array if you would like to

```
            List<Person> allPersons = await firebaseHelper.GetAllPersons();
            List<string> allNames = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in allPersons)
            {
                allNames.Add(item.Name);
            }
            string[] Names= allNames.ToArray();
```